# "Assisting delivery of construction program " vs "Assisting with delivery of construction program"

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I recently came across the phrase "assisting delivery of construction programs". Is this phrase grammatically correct?   I would write: "Assisting **with** delivery of construction programs".

Could someone please let me know which phrase is correct? Or are both phrases are correct and have the same meaning?

Note: This phrase is quoted from a CV. The full phrase is, "Assisting delivery of construction programs and reactive maintenance".

Comment: Please include the text that surrounded this phrase to provide context. As it stands, neither is grammatically correct.

Comment: Hello Mike, Thanks a lot for your comment. This sentence/phrase is from CV. It is a description of the task that person performed in that particular role. The full phrase is" Assisting delivery of construction programs and reactive maintenance.

Comment: Sorry I spelled you name incorrectly. My apologies Mick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phrase, "assisting delivery of construction programs", is not grammatically correct.

One would normally use *is* or *with*, and either with or without an article:

- "assisting in the delivery of construction programs";
- "assisting with the delivery of construction programs"; or
- "assisting in delivery of construction programs"
- "assisting with delivery of construction programs"

I would consider the formulation using *in the* or *with the* as normal grammar, but just using *in* or *with* is also quite common in a list such as might appear in a CV.

What sometimes happens is that articles and prepositions are dropped in lists such as these (e.g. in CVs) either to save a little on space or, what seems to be more common, to sound *[punchier](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/punchy)*.

What this leads to is, when someone writes their skills or responsibilities in a list in their CV, that they [may] start with:

```
One of my responsibilities was assisting in the delivery of construction programs.
```

This becomes a list item such as:

```
- assisting in the delivery of construction programs
```

which then is edited to remove all the "unnecessary" words and perhaps sound more dynamic:

```
- assisting delivery of construction programs
```

Comment: I know that I shouldn't be using comments box to say Thanks a lot Mick, but unfortunately I couldn't find the way to say thanks a lot. If you could please let me know how to do it it would be great. Thank you very much for your answer it was really detailed and clear.